# how to point a pointer to string without declaring string directly

Tags: c, string, pointers, c-strings

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char *ch = "Hello, World";//character pointer pointing to a string without declaration.
    printf("%s", ch);//printing the string without <i>dereferencing</i> it.
}
```

I saw an example in a book, with code as given above. I don't understand how a character pointer points to a string without declaring a string first.
Also there is no *dereference* operator used to print the string.

Comment: I would rather use *str* or *s* since the variable is a pointer and not a character. Also you want to declare it as `const char *str` to prevent modification of the string constant it points to.

Answer (score 2):

As stated very well by @tryurbest, **Why it works with pointers:**

When you say `char * ch` in C, you are allocating a pointer in the memory. When you write `char *ch = "Hello, World";`, you are creating a string literal in memory and making the pointer point to it. When you create another string literal "new string" and assign it to `ch`, all you are doing is changing where the pointer points.

On the other hand, for added information, **Why it doesn't work with arrays:**

When you say char ch1 [] = "Hello, World", you are creating a string literal and putting it in the array during its definition. It is ok to not give a size, as the array calculates it and appends a '\0' to it. You cannot reassign anything to that array without resizing it.

Hope this helps to clarify some things.

Comment: _"You cannot reassign anything to that array without resizing it"_ What does this mean?

Comment: What I mean is that you can't do `ch1 = "hello"` where you are assigning something to the new array.

Answer (score 1):

`"Hello, World"` is a **string literal** or read only memory store in **data** block. A variable `ch` is pointer to char, which is initialized with the location of the first character.

Answer (score 0):

That's simply how printf works with a const char* argument. (Your pointer actually points to const data.)

Starting at the memory location denoted by the pointer, it prints character by character until a NUL terminator is reached.

The C standard library string functions all work in this way. Simply put it's how the language models strings.